# Слово "дока"

Tags: этимология

"Дока" — мастер в чем-то, специалист. А что это за слово? Оно, вообще, русское?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Фасмера указаны 2 возможных варианта образования этого слова:

1. от лат. doctus, doctor "ученый"; см. Горяев, ЭС 93; Преобр. 1, 188.
2. исконнорусск., от до́шлый, см. Зеленин (РФВ 54, 118)